# Make text show up on hover over button

Tags: html, css

What I want to do is have something like this:

```
<button class="addMore">+</button>
```

Do an effect like this:

https://i.gyazo.com/d353b657df39c0e6ff159bfdb713f6a4.mp4

when you hover over it.

I've been able to find a few different things for this but none that act as I want it to in the video.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Use `title` in order to display your message:

```html
<button class="addMore" title="click here">+</button>
```

Comment: Follow up question, is it possible to style that?

Comment: Doesn't work on buttons which are disabled. 
To make it work, set the button CSS  to "pointer-events: auto".

Answer (score 3):

```css
.addMore{
  border: none;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #eee;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.addMore:hover{
  border: 1px solid #888;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<button class="addMore" title="Hover on me!">+</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<button type='submit' title='Add New Item'>+</button>
```

Comment: Hi @MoJo, welcome to stackoverflow! You're answering a question which is over 2 years old. Please try to answer new questions, this would be more helpful.

Comment: This duplicates the answer given and accepted 2½ years earlier

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background color change of button using css as follows,

```
.addMore:hover {
   background-color: #545454; //desired color code
}
```

and set the tooltip as `<button class="addMore" title="click here">+</button>`

Answer (score 0):

For all my `React.JS`ers out there, (and for folks that come after), I was able to achieve this by doing (and using the [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/) lib):

Usage of Tooltip component

```
import { Button } from 'reactstrap'

<Tooltip
  tooltipContent={
    'You cannot cancel invoices that were created automatically by memberships!'
  }
  component={
    <span id={'cancelButton'}>
      <Button
        style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}
        onClick={...}
        disabled
      >
        Cancel
      </Button>
    </span>
  }
/>
```

Tooltip.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import * as Reactstrap from 'reactstrap'

const Tooltip = props => {
  const [tooltipOpen, setTooltipOpen] = useState(false)
  const toggle = () => setTooltipOpen(!tooltipOpen)
  // Warnings for component useage
  if (!props.component) {
    console.warn('Missing component for tooltip')
  }
  if (!props.tooltipContent) {
    console.warn('Missing content for tooltip')
  }
  if (props.component && !props.component.props.id) {
    console.warn('Component for tooltip has no id (must not have spaces)')
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {props.component}
      {props.tooltipContent && (
        <Reactstrap.Tooltip
          placement={props.placement ? props.placement : 'top'}
          isOpen={tooltipOpen}
          target={props.component.props.id}
          toggle={toggle}
          delay={props.delay ? props.delay : 750}
        >
          {props.tooltipContent && (
            <div className="row p-2">
              <div className="col-md-12">{props.tooltipContent}</div>
            </div>
          )}
        </Reactstrap.Tooltip>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
Tooltip.displayName = 'Tooltip'
export default Tooltip
```

The most important parts are the `style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}` on the `<Button />` element and the nesting of the Button within a `<span />`

Answer (score 0):

If you don´t want to use the title attribute you can do it with HTML and CSS only.

Like this example:

HTML

```
<button class="read-more-info-icon modal-right">i<span class="hidden-info">More information about the matter...</span></button>
```

CSS

```
button.read-more-info-icon {
    vertical-align: top;
    background: #bfbfbf;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1;
    color: black!important;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
button.read-more-info-icon:hover {
    overflow: visible;
}
button.read-more-info-icon .hidden-info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 23px;
    width: 240px;
    text-align: left;
    background: black;
    padding: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  color:#fff;
}
button.read-more-info-icon.modal-left .hidden-info { 
    right: 0;
}
button.read-more-info-icon.modal-right .hidden-info { 
    left: 0;
}
button.read-more-info-icon:hover .hidden-info {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Example on codepen:
https://codepen.io/SitefactoryDK/pen/eYLQKvm